# Linux Bash Script Regex malfunction

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I would like to make a bash script, which should decide about the given strings, if they fulfill the term or not.

The terms are:

- The string's first 3 character must be "le-"
- Between hyphens there can any number of consonant in any arrangement, just one "e" and it cannot contain any vowel.
- Between hyphens there must be something
- The string must not end with hyphen

I made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Testing regex

while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^le((-[^aeiou\W]*e+[^aeiou\W]*)+)$ ]]
        then
           printf "\""$line"\"\t\t\t-> True\n";
        else
           printf "\""$line"\"\t\t\t-> False\n";
        fi
done < <(cat "$@")
```

It does everything fine, except one thing:
It says true no matter how many hyphens are next to each other.
For example:
It says true for this string "le--le"

I tried this regex expression on websites (like [this](https://regex101.com/r/gL6hE3/1)) and they worked without this malfunction.
All I can think of there must be something difference between the web page and the linux bash. (All I can see on the web page is it runs PHP)

Do you have got any idea, how could I make it work ?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sweaver2112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244811/sweaver2112) rightly points out that the `\W` is causing you problems, but fails to provide a working example of a bash test regex that does what you ask (at least, i couldn't get it to work).

this seems to do it (adapting [Laurel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel)'s consonant regex):

```
[[ "$line" =~ ^le(-[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*e[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*)+$ ]]
```

it matches (e.g.):

```
le-e
le-e-le
le-e-e-e-e-e
```

and more generally:

```
le-([[:consonant:]]*e[[:consonant:]]*)+
```

and doesn't match (e.g.):

```
le-
le--le
le-lea-le
```

also, you can write it more cleanly this way:

```
c='[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]'
[[ "$line" =~ ^le(-$c*e$c*)+$ ]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: this regex does NOT prevent two E's from being inside dashes: 'le-eseseeeeeeeeess-se-se' use pcregrep and you can use lookaheads.

Comment: you're right! i forgot that e is a vowel. fixed by changing `b-h` to `b-df-h`.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one problem with your regex:  `[^aeiou\W]` - a negated "non-word", means "word" - and it [matches any letter](https://regex101.com/r/tI8rZ9/1), consonants included. Character classes are inclusive, not exclusive. We're better off just listing all the consonants (and for you case, we'll add 'e' and '-' to the set as well).

So try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/vT1iR8/6): (*edit*: using @Laurel's more concise char class)

```
`(?=^le-)(?!.*--)(?!.*-[^-]*e[^-]*e[^-]*-)[b-hj-np-tv-z-]*[^-]$`
```

- `(?=^le-)` starts with 'le-'
- `(?!.*--)` no double dashes allowed
- `(?!.*-[^-]*e[^-]*e[^-]*-)` do NOT see two e's between dashes
- `[b-hj-np-tv-z-]*` - consume consonants, e, and dashes (same as `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstlvwze-]`)
- `[^-]$` last character must be non-dash

Comment: You can shorten that char class: `[a-hj-np-tvwz-]`. Any reason why you had TWO `l`s?

Comment: one problem with this here regex... it doesn't work inside `bash` test: `bash: !.*--: event not found`

Comment: @webb That's a separate problem; you want to turn off csh-style history expansion (`set +H` IIRC).

Comment: But Bash doesn't support PCRE extensions so this cannot work.

Comment: most modern systems have pcregrep which does